# Installed 64-bit ubuntu on 32-bit windows vista

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am not very knowledgeable about computing, so pardon me if I am asking a stupid question.

I installed ubuntu on my 32-bit windows vista via http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

So after installing, I realised that I have installed a 64-bit ubuntu. Is that a problem, having a dual boot of 64-bit ubuntu and 32 bit windows vista?

Answer (score 0):

urm i dont think so, i have done it on an old compaq laptop that came with windows vista 32 bit preinstalled, i managed to dual boot with ubuntu 12.04 64bit, then replace vista with windows 7 64bit (non genuine) and it worked perfectly..

i say WORKED and not works because i dropped the laptop and well if you drop a laptop older than 3 years they are like a puzzle of wires with plastic shards stuck in them haha

all i would have suggested is to check that your Processor supports the 64 bit architecture  but seeing as you have got the 64bit OS working then im guessing it does, well done for the dual boot by the way, i have one myself:)

Good luck on your future experiences into UBUNTU:D you will learn how much windows holds you back like a window:)